# SSL certificate error - Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I'm using requests in Jupyter notebooks to make a connection to 'https://dynamodb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/ (Amazon AWS) & have been getting the error :-

> SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))

It works with `verify=False` but I don't want to implement this due to security.

I've been googling solutions for days, trying to set `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` from `cacert.pem` to `weak.pem`, setting `SSL_CERT_FILE` similarly, using certifi old_where instead of where, downgrading certifi, reinstalling requests with `requests[security]` - nothing has worked so far. I can connect fine via my browser, so it must be requests or Jupyter notebooks that has the problem or rather is missing the certificate.. I'm able to use requests to other https locations - I'm not sure if they are using SSL encryption or not. I don't know if I need to enable something in the environment or whether I need to get the AWS certificate into my environment variables (and also I don't know how to do either!)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I tried a simple GET request with `requests.get('https://dynamodb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/')` on my jupyter notebook and got `r.content` as `b'healthy: dynamodb.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com '` and `status_code` as `200`. Are you doing a POST request? Please show how you are making the request and the full traceback error.

Comment: I'm making the exact same request and the full traceback error is as above - obviously something in my environment is different to yours - I can bring back b'healthy via a browser but nothing using requests as the SSL handshake doesn't work

Comment: Could you share your environment details, such as OS, Python & requests version, openssl version? Have you tried this request on a different computer with a similar/different environment?